# Compodoc Documentation How to Hide Public Properties and Show Spec Files

Tags: angular, testing, documentation, compodoc

I am working on Compodoc (https://compodoc.app/guides/getting-started.html) documentation for my Angular application and am trying to figure out how to do the following:

1. Hide public properties without having to use `@Ignore`. Should I just do this through custom CSS?
2. Show the `spec.ts` file for each component in a tab just like Source, Template, and Styles are shown.
3. How to implement an "Example" tab. Where do I add the actual example code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use storybook for the examples side of things

Comment: @JakeSmith isn't there a way to add a basic example or a live example for each of your components via a tab? It shows a live example here in the docs: https://compodoc.app/guides/live-example-tab.html. And here it talks about tab config: https://compodoc.app/guides/tab-configuration.html. And here is a basic example: https://github.com/compodoc/compodoc/issues/188. But it's not clear to me how I get that Example tab to actually show up. Thanks

Comment: it looks like it is possible, yes.  But according to the github issue you linked, those extra custom pages are just html files that you have to manage yourself.  when compodoc builds, it doesn't know about those custom pages, so you have to add your own script to copy those over during compodoc generation, and then yes, you can add a new tab via their tab configuration like you gave links to the documentation of.  But this is probably more work than its worth because you'll essentially have to run angular manually on each example page to be able to render your angular component like you want.

Comment: Storybook would make this easier to generate, but you would have two different documentation sites, one for compodoc and one for storybook.